# Can someone explain the difference between "face project" and "face nearest" in snapping?

Tags: modeling, snapping

Im a newbie to blender and i was just wondering what are the difference between face project and face nearest, i understand that face nearest only allow the object to move within the target object, however im not sure what face project does exactly, and also inside face project there is an option called "project individual elements", what does it do exactly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html

Comment: I have the same question. I cannot get Face Project to function.

Answer (score 0):

### *Face project*

This is best explained by example. Lets say you have a row of verts (or a number of objects) you want to fit against another mesh. Select 'active' from the tabs at the top of the snap dropdown, make the active element your pivot point and rotate the view so that one vert is in front of face that you want it to snap to and make it active. Now move the selection slightly. You want to keep it in front of the selected face. The vertices will appear not to move but when you change the view you'll see they have been projected onto the target object. That's the simplest way – once you get a feel for it you can try with different snap with and pivot point settings. Note the manual is a bit misleading when it talks about the cursor position – all that really matters is your view as the name suggests.

### *Face Nearest*

*Face Nearest* is more straightforward, though in my experience a bit flakey. (With a large number of elements and/or a surface that curves too much things can get funky. For best results work in smallish batches.) Think of it as snapping each element in a group to its nearest face once you've moved them as a group (though of course the snapping process is in real time).

What 'project individual elements' is meant to do is anybody's guess. It's enabled by default when using face project and turning it off just disables the snap. In 'face nearest' it does something funky which may or may not be useful, the logic of which escapes me. My guess is that it's something to do with backward compatibility